# Looping and displaying data from 2 seperate arrays Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, ngfor

I'm using Angular 4 & Firebase to store my data.

I fetched all of the "Clients" from my database and stored it in 
"this.clients".
Everything is fine but I can't display the $key from Firebase (others works fine).

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.clientService.getClients().valueChanges().subscribe(clients => {
    this.clients = clients;
    console.log(this.clients);
  });
}
```

So, to get the $key I made another array and function to get the key only using `snapshotChanges()` instead of `valueChanges()`
like this:

```js
this.clientService.getClientsKey().snapshotChanges().subscribe(clientsKey => {
  this.clientsKey = clientsKey;
  console.log(this.clientsKey);
});
```

This works and the log is fine!
Now when looping on the component HTML I can view it perfectly.

**BUT** I need it to be in the same table and not to be duplicated:
Is there any way I can fix it?
This is my current table:

```html
<table class="table table-striped" *ngIf="clients?.length > 0; else noClients">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let client of clients">
      <td *ngFor="let k of clientsKey">{{ k.key }}</td>
      <td>{{ client.firstName }} {{ client.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ client.balance | currency }}</td>
      <td><a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i> Details</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Duplicate on each table row instead of showing one id per time]

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `clients array` and `clientsKey array` are of same length you can do this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let client of clients; let index = index">
        <td>{{ clientsKey[index].key }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.firstName }} {{ client.lastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.balance | currency }}</td>
        <td><a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i> Details</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Listen to me closely, you are a genius. Thank you so much for being so awesome!!! YOU ARE THE BEST!

Comment: @AvivDay Haha! Thank You :) Also, please accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to iterate over one array only and map the indexes of first array with the second one while painting the values. Refer below template.

```
<table class="table table-striped" *ngIf="clients?.length > 0; else noClients">
         <thead class="thead-inverse">
          <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Balance</th>
           <th></th>
           </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index">
            <td>{{ clientsKey[i].key }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.firstName }} {{ client.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.balance | currency }}</td>
            <td><a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i> Details</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```